# Fastest way to convert a Dictionary<K,V> to List<V>

Tags: c#, performance, list, dictionary

in c#, what is the fastest way to convert a dictionary of about 100 entries to a list? I m currently using

```
myDictionary.Values.ToList();
```

but when I look at the source code of the Values property, it seems to create a copy of the dictionary, which seems slow. I don't need a copy, is there a fastest way?

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection Values
    {
      [__DynamicallyInvokable] get
      {
        if (this.values == null)
          this.values = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection(this);
        return this.values;
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you've only got 100 items then is performance really an issue?

Comment: And rather than guessing that it "seems slow" have you performed any benchmarks to compare actual performance with your requirements?

Comment: How do you use the list you want to get? Maybe a different type would be optimal for you, like `IEnumerable<V>` or `ICollection<V>`.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't create a copy of the dictionary, it just creates an instance of a class that is nested in `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, the [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection`-class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8bctb9c(v=vs.110).aspx). As input the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a4z141d(v=vs.110).aspx) takes the dictionary to read it's values. As noted that is an  O(1) operation.

`Enumerable.ToList` will create a new list from those values. In my opinion this approach is efficient and readable. By using `ToList` you are uncoupling the values from the dictionary itself which seems to be desired.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help:

```
var list= new List<V>(myDictionary.Values);
```

Comment: I don't see how that's any better than `var list = myDictionary.Values.ToList()`

Comment: To be more specific, the OP is worried about the allocation that's happening _during_ `myDictionary.Values`; so since you're still calling the same operation...